# Java - Creating new list from old list, old list getting modified when modifying new list

Tags: java, collections, cloning

I have two objects which are added in List. I created a copy of oldList to newList. When i am changing newList, oldList is also getting modified.

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(1,"SACHIN","INDIA");
Employee e2 = new Employee(2,"SEHWAG","INDIA");
List<Employee> oldList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
oldList.add(e1);
oldList.add(e2);

List<Employee> newList = new ArrayList<Employee>(oldList);

newList.get(0).setTeam("INDIALEGENDS");
newList.get(1).setTeam("INDIALEGENDS");
```

When i am modifying newList, oldList is also getting updated with new values.
NOTE: Employee class is not serialized

Comment: You are not modifying `newList` or `oldList`, you are modifying *something* that they contain, that is something very different. You have two separate lists and adding or removing objects from them does not affect the other. But you only have two employees and those two employees are present in both lists. You need to clone the employees as well, not just their references.

Comment: read about Deep copy and shallow copy

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. I have cloned Employee objects using deep cloning and it is working fine now.